# Adding content under image grid to span length of page

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for some advice on an image grid I'm working on.

Using this as an example: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_image_grid_responsive

Say I wanted to add something like this underneath every image in that HTML:

```
<div>This is my piece of very long content that I want to display under all images in a row. It should span underneath all images.</div>
```

This content would be hidden by default and some action would make it show (such as clicking on a particular image). What I'm trying to achieve is so that this div (or whatever it ends up being) displays the length of the page, depending on how long the page is. So if there are 4 images across, the text would show under the first four images. If there are two images across (due to resolution size changes), it would show under two. This is opposed to it showing just under the image that it sits under in the HTML.

Not sure how to best write that - any advice?

Comment: you want to show the text on hover the img?

Comment: I don't mean to be negative in any way, but to be honest this isn't a great question because there are lots of different ways you could go about doing this and there are quite a few open requirements.  If you want some advice though, I'd suggest looking into taking a mobile-first approach.  You could structure this so every image has text associated with it first and then go from there.  But I would try some things first and then try to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I have some jquery setup so that when you click on an image, content shows up. I want that content to display responsively (like that image grid example) but to span the full row of images that is displaying, rather than just the one the content lives under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way could be to use some additional markup around the images. You can manually add it or use javascript to dynamically construct it.

Here's an example. I'm not positive it's the effect you're looking for.

I inserted a div around the image and included a span with the text to display below (did it for 3 of the images.)

This is the css for a hover effect.

```
.column div span{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    left:0;
    background: #0095ff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
.column div:hover span{
    display:block;
}
```

The added markup will be something like:

```
<div>
 <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
 <span>This is some text</span>
</div>
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 32px;
}

.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 0 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create four equal columns that sits next to each other */
.column {
    -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
    flex: 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0 4px;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 50%;
        flex: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        -ms-flex: 100%;
        flex: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}

.column div span{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    left:0;
    background: #0095ff;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding:20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
}
.column div:hover span{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="column">
    <div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <span>This is some text</span>
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <span>Other text</span>
    </div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <span>More text</span>
    </div>
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/falls2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/nature.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mist.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/paris.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/ocean.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/wedding.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/mountainskies.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/rocks.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/underwater.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was after. Thank you @signal2013!